# Calculation of Mean and Std of Phototour dataset

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, std, mean

I've got a question about the calculation of Mean and Std of Phototour dataset.

Phototour dataset provides corresponding patches with all shape of `(64,64,1)` to train a descriptor (usually CNN networks).
These patches are extracted from original images. these original images are captured by tourists from all around the world from specific locations (Notredame, Liberty, Yosemite) with different image resolutions. center of every patch (32, 32) is a keyPoint that detected by SIFT detector.
for example, in these datasets we have nearly 500K patchs that extracted from 715 images for Notredame.

The link to the dataset:
http://phototour.cs.washington.edu/

In Pytorch Phototour dataset they defined those as below:

```
means = {'notredame': 0.4854, 'yosemite': 0.4844, 'liberty': 0.4437,
         'notredame_harris': 0.4854, 'yosemite_harris': 0.4844, 'liberty_harris': 0.4437}
stds = {'notredame': 0.1864, 'yosemite': 0.1818, 'liberty': 0.2019,
        'notredame_harris': 0.1864, 'yosemite_harris': 0.1818, 'liberty_harris': 0.2019}
```

1. How can I reproduce these two parameters?
2. I must calculate Mean and Std on **extracted patches** or on **original images**?

Comment: Could you please elaborate with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: What do you mean by *extracted patches*?

Comment: Yes, sure @LazyCoder. I've edited the post with extra explanations.

Comment: @Ivan I've edited the post but in addition, every patch has extracted from an image. center of patch (32, 32) is a keyPoint that detected by SIFT detector. in these datasets we have nearly 500K patch that extracted from 715 images.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would measure the mean and standard deviation on your training set. You would usually have to measure both for each feature (or channels: there's a single channel here). Here *Notre Dame*, *Yosemite*, and *Liberty* are somewhat considered as three separate datasets:

> Follow the links below to download zipfiles *for each of the 3 datasets*

Futhermore, it makes sense for it to correspond to the mean/std of extracted patches. Since [`torchvision.datasets.PhotoTour`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html#phototour) is the dataset containing the 16x16-patch grids associated with the paper *[Learning Local Image Descriptors Data](http://phototour.cs.washington.edu/patches/default.htm) [1]*.

*[1]: S. Winder and M. Brown. Learning Local Image Descriptors. To appear International Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition (CVPR2007)*

Comment: thanks for your answer. So you mean to calculate mean and std on extracted patches?

Comment: Yes, if you want to work with this dataset and wish to measure the values yourself.

Comment: plz look at these values for Mean of Notredame dataset at pytorch official implementation: 'notredame': 0.4854    and    'notredame_harris': 0.4854. these two dataset are from same location but they have totally different patches. So why the Mean of them are equal?